# How to use a python library from github

Tags: python, git, api, cpanel

I have little experience in Python and want to use this Python library to interface with an API: [Python cPanel API library](https://github.com/vexxhost/python-cpanelapi)

However, it does not give me any instructions on how to install. I tried `pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/vexxhost/python-cpanelapi#egg=cpanelapi` gives me the error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/src/cpanelapi/setup.py'`

The repo contains a `__init__.py`, `client.py` and `exceptions.py` file.

How do I use and install this library?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the "but that doesn't work"? Do you get any erros?

Comment: Have you tried just copying the cpanelapi folder into your local workspace, and importing and using it directly? It is not something you need to install.

Comment: Ah, you're trying to install a repository that doesn't offer a package setup. Use the method from Unsigned_Arduino

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks, I did that and it seems to work. However, where do I put it when I want to install it system-wide?

Comment: You will have to create your own app/package that wraps around this cpanelapi. Then you can `pip install` it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the repository.
2. Move it to the base of your directory (along with your scripts)
3. Import it with `import cpanelapi`